# Birthday money calculator

Tags: java

My assignment is to create a calculator that can calculate how much is left on a giftcard after purchasing an item, but also making sure not to go over 6 items, or $225, whichever comes first. I know I need another method to do a calculation but i'm not sure what to put in it. This is what I have so far:

I know I will need a for loop for the counter for the items, but I'm really stuck. I posted the actual assignment to give background.

> For your birthday, your rich aunt & uncle give you a $225 gift card to
>   the local mall. They will go shopping with you and will help carry out
>   your items. The most that each of you can carry is one item in each
>   hand. Thus, you may purchase a maximum of six items. You will have a
>   tracker device that computes the number of items you purchase as well
>   as the amount of money you have spent. After you choose each item, the
>   tracker prompts you for the price, and then displays the amount of
>   money you have spent. Then it displays the number of items you may
>   still choose and the balance on the gift card. The program will not
>   terminate until you reach 6 items or $225, whichever comes first. The
>   tracker then will list the total spent & the number of items as well
>   as the balance on the gift card.
>
> **Required:**
>
> - validate that negative
>     prices are not entered and that you can’t spend more than the balance
>     on the gift card. Give the user as many opportunities as needed to
>     enter a price above 0 or below 225. User should be able to purchase
>     items costing between one penny and $225, inclusive.
> - all dollar
>     amounts should be formatted for currency using the NumberFormat class.
> - Include at least 1 method in your program.
>
> *Be sure to create test cases for all options:*
>
> - spend the entire dollar amount on fewer than 6 items
> - purchase 6 items totaling less than the entire dollar amount
> - spend the entire dollar amount on exactly 6 items

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double priceItem = 0, totalPrice = 225, currentPrice = 0;
    int numItem;

    System.out.println("Happy birthday from Auntie and Uncle! \nYou may purchase up to"
            + " 6 items with this gift card of $225.");

    for (numItem = 1; numItem <= 6; numItem++) {
        System.out.println("Enter the price for item #" + numItem + ": ");

        priceItem = input.nextDouble();

        while (numItem <= 6 && totalPrice <= 225) {

            totalPrice = currentPrice - priceItem;
            System.out.println("You may buy this item. You have spent ");

            if (currentPrice > totalPrice) {
                System.out.println("Item is too expensive. Balance on gift card is " + currentPrice);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I have tried to make a while loop, it is an infinite loop and again I'm not sure which calculation to put in to get it to break.

Comment: looks like homework

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to give you the answer as it is something you should solve yourself but I will give a few pointers.

1. Your use of a while loop here is incorrect, do you really need a while loop?
2. `if(totalPrice <= 225) break;`

Perhaps look into the break statement to exit the loop when a certain condition is met, that why you can ensure there are 6 items or less and it is not over 225.

You also need to handle an entry of 0 as it is a penny minimum and you cannot allow them to exceed 225.

```
priceItem = input.nextDouble();
while(priceItem < 0.01 || priceItem > 225){
System.out.println("Item Price cannot be 0 or greater than 225, please...");
priceItem = input.nextDouble();
}
```

You also can't allow a value that exceeds the remaining balance, I will let you try and figure out how to do that yourself. What you have done so far isn't bad you just need to break it down a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would construct it:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        double balance = 225.0;
        double itemPrice = 0;
        int boughtItems = 0;
        int maxItems = 6;

        System.out.println("Happy birthday from Auntie and Uncle! \nYou may purchase up to"
                            + " 6 items with this gift card of $225.");

        while(boughtItems < maxItems && balance > 0) {
            System.out.print("You have " + balance + "$ on your giftcard. \nEnter the price for item #" + (boughtItems + 1) + ": ");
            itemPrice = input.nextDouble();
            if(balance - itemPrice > 0.0) {
                balance -= itemPrice;
                System.out.println("You have bought the Item!\n\n\nYou can carry " + (maxItems - boughtItems - 1) + " more things!\n");
                boughtItems++;
            } else {
                if(balance - itemPrice == 0) {
                    balance -= itemPrice;
                    boughtItems++;
                    System.out.println("\nYou have spent all your money.");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("You dont have enough money for this Item!\n\n\n");
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("You bought " + boughtItems + " item/s. " + "Have fun with the stuff!");
    }
```

You can write a `buy(double balance, double price)` method for example, so you fill in the assignment requirements.

And of course you need to do the rest of the stuff like the number-formatting.

Answer (score -2):

In the while loop, you are doing wrong assignment, that’s why infinite loop.
Assign currentPrice is equal to totalPrice - price for item purchased.

Comment: The problem seems to be that the `while` has no place in there at all

Comment: So do I need another method for the current price calculation or just keep it all in the main?

Comment: @chspats you can remove for loop and keep the while loop just with number of purchases less than 6 condition and a if loop inside to check for sufficient funds to purchase an item. If don’t have sufficient funds break while loop.

Comment: @Vipul do you think it would be better to get rid of the for loop or get rid of the while loop?

Comment: Remove for loop and keep the while loop. Refer 'user12046842' solution.

Comment: Okay so I figured it out by using a for loop, but now I'm stuck on the part about showing how much the user has spent so far. I tried doing balance - item price but that wasn't working. Any advice?

Comment: what are the actual and expected results? Could you show the code, so we can figure it out.

Comment: This is what is expected: Happy Birthday from Auntie & Uncle!
 You may purchase up to 6 items with this gift card of $225.
Enter the price for item #1: 98.89
You may buy this item. You have spent $98.89 so far.
You may buy up to 5 more items. Gift card balance: $126.11                        Also then test cases for making sure item is greater than a penny, but I figured that part out. Just the balance left is what i'm stuck on

Comment: I feel like I need some kind of counter for the amount that I have spent, because trying to just subtract the two isn't working